# Assign dataframe name to a variable in a function

Tags: r

I have created a function and passing data frame as a parameter to the function. Now, I would like to take that data frame name as a string and store it into as a string variable.

Code used:

```
RFun <- function(a){
    args=(commandArgs(TRUE))
    l<<-80
    h<<-85
    fname<<-paste(a,"_Temp.csv")
    a_R<-filter(a_RW,cs==2|cs==3)
    a_R<-a_Rinse[-c(2,3)]
    write.csv(a_R,file=fname,row.names=FALSE)
    a_Rinse_Temperature_Deviations <- read.csv(paste("~/",fname"))
}

RFun(df)
```

From the above function when I try to execute it is creating numeric variables `l` and `h` with values which I have specified, but `fname` is creating for the complete data frame with rows and columns and it is not storing as I require here.

It is taking lot of time for execution as well.

Expected `fname` should be **`df_Temp.csv`**. Where `df` is the data frame.

Comment: try Rfun("df");  fname <- paste0(a,"_Temp.csv")

Comment: @VenYao it is giving error 1 "Error in filter(a, cs== 2) : object 'cs' not found"

Comment: please give a minimum working example. @Pallavi

Comment: when i add $ to that respective column name then again error as "Error in a$cs : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
In addition: Warning message:
In filter(a, a$cs == 2) : NAs introduced by coercion

Answer (score 1):

Looks like **assign(String varName , obj Value)** might get you where you need to be.

```
RFun<-function(a){
args=(commandArgs(TRUE))
l<<-80
h<<-85
fname <<- "File_Name_Text"
assign (fname,paste(a,"_Temp.csv"))
a_R<-filter(a_RW,cs==2|cs==3)
a_R<-a_Rinse[-c(2,3)]
write.csv(a_R,file=fname,row.names=FALSE)
a_Rinse_Temperature_Deviations <- read.csv(paste("~/",fname))  
}
```

Comment: not working as expected when i try to assign values to a variable. In conditions it is not checking those variables and performing as expected

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how you expect it to work. But I suspect that you are trying to access the string fname when you want to be accessing the df **get(fname)**. Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to follow without a working example. But try to assign only the "name" of your df instead of the complete df. Try this:

```
fname <<- paste(deparse(substitute(a)),"_Temp.csv",sep="")
```